# Is there a way to "re-initialize" JavaScript after an error occurred?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

We are currently using the following code to track javascript errors on our website:

```
window.onerror = function(message) {
    log(message);
};
```

The log-function in the code above displays the error message within the console for developers but not for regular users. We are thinking about displaying some kind of information for regular users and then to reload the page after the user confirms the message.
It would however be better if we could figure out a way to make sure that javascript continues to work even after an error has occurred.
So we are wondering if there is a way to "re-initialize" javascript to start over after an error has occurred. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Best solution: write your JS such that no such unexpected errors happen. This should be pretty easy in a small app. It's a bit harder in a larger app, but it shouldn't be *that* much harder. Worst-case, test to find them, and if you don't, launch it, then if any come in, fix them as needed (which is what Stack Exchange does).

Comment: I would assume that he's asking how to re-initialize JavaScript because he actually wants to know how... Not because he wants to be told that he should just avoid doing what he wants. Saying "just don't make any mistakes" is not a valid solution for "how do I do x thing after I catch a mistake?"

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if you've already tried this, but did you try a "try catch" block?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

This will allow it to encounter an error, and then move on. In the "catch" block you could do something with error, but you can also just run other code as well after the error has occurred.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have used try / catch before but I am not sure if there is a way to use this on a global scale. Do you know if there is a way to use try / catch for all the javascript-code on a website? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure about that. Is it okay to reload the page instead? Probably not, but location.reload() would refresh the page and because of that, re-load the javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I would like to avoid if possible. I will try to implement the solution suggested in luek baja's answer. If this doesn't work I will probably go with the reload instead. Thank you again!

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. Yeah, luek baja's answer looks pretty cool. You might check in on any eventListeners to make sure they aren't still there from the first time. I feel like I've tried something similar in the past and had left-over listeners that were causing new problems.

Comment: Thank you for the tipp. I will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to re-initialize your code (other than reloading the page), but here is a way you could do it:

Save a copy of the object key names in the `window` object. Wrap your starting code in a function and call the function once on startup. If you ever detect an error, delete all key-value pairs from the `window` object that were not saved in the original copy; this will delete all global vars. Finally, call your initialize function again.

This may have some complications when implementing, but should work most of the time.

As @That'sIs JustCrazy said, left over event listeners may be a problem, so you will also need a way to reset the DOM. You can save a copy of the original contents of your `html` tag at the beginning, `const savedHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML`. Then run `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = savedHTML`. I do remember reading somewhere that deleting elements with event listeners will cause memory leaks on IE, but on other browsers it is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This sounds interesting. I will try to implement that on the website.

Comment: If you do have problems with event listeners like @That'sIsJustCrazy said, I've edited my answer to include another concept that may be of use.